# JQuery Datatables Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working on a web project, where I have used [JQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) in the project, the only challenge that I am facing with is, how to get or access datatable's properties and vlues like: search value, order, limit, ... using JavaScript and JQuery.
Thanks in advance.

Some Code I have Used:

```
function loadDestroyedGoods() {
    var start_date = $("#start_date").val();
    var end_date = $("#end_date").val();
    if (start_date && end_date) {
        var dataTable = $('.g_tbl').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "destroy": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "lengthMenu": [20, 50, 100, 500, 1000],
            "pageLength": 10,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/loadGoodsDestroyed",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "json",
                "dataSrc": "data",
                "data": {start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date}
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "status"},
                {"data": "count"},
                {"data": "price"},
                {"data": "consumer"},
                {"data": "date"}
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

This is what I want:

What I want is how to get data-tables' properties, not how to load custom data into it. I don't need server side engagement here, all I want is how to get the value which user entered for the search, the order user used to order the rows

Comment: Please give us more details about what you want to do, expected result, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: User searches and loads his/her required data using the datatable, and then he/she wants to print that data, so I need his/her customization info on datatable to be able to print such data to him/her

Comment: so I want to get datatable's info and forward it to the server side to get the customized datatable's data back and then print it

Comment: Indeed I want to print the data in a custom format and page.

Comment: you can use `data` object available for datatable where it contains each row. Please check https://datatables.net/manual/server-side for more information

Comment: do you mean how to pass search sort parameters to server side (controller or something?)

Comment: I mean how to get search or sort, ... values through javascript, and have it available on my javascript code

Answer (score 0):

you can add following line to your javascript to extract global search filter value. (if you are using same table that you linked, not changed any id of table).

here is code for search field on that page:

[image]

below query looks for `example filter` id in your page which is div id, inside that it looks for `label` tag, in it there is `input type="search"` , so i used below which extract the value of that search field.

```
    $("#example_filter > label > input").val();
```

here is proof of its work :

[image]

and you can get sorting column name and index (it includes default sort on page load also) using this script :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    $("#example").dataTable().bind('click', function () {
      var order = table.order();
      alert( 'Table is ordered by column: '+order[0][0]+', direction:' + order[0][1]);
      var title = table.column(order[0][0]).header();
       alert( 'Ordering column title: '+$(title).html() );
        });

    var order = table.order();
    alert( 'Table is ordered by column: '+order[0][0]+', direction:' + order[0][1]);

    var title = table.column(order[0][0]).header();
    alert( 'Ordering column title: '+$(title).html() );
});
```

Comment: would you please provide a bit details, Thank you

Comment: label?, input?, #example_fileter?

Comment: @BCK don't forgot to marked it as accepted and upvote, if it helps you to solve your problem.